# Error: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo (SDK v25)

Tags: android

I'm loosing my mind here... I have gone through all relevant answers here on stackoverflow...

I have this app that has been working OK for some time.

Recently I changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion (both to 25) and this has brought down all sorts of problems on me :-(

For starters I'm faced with the dreaded

> Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{[path to main activity]}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "[path to main
>   activity]" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/[my
>   app]/base.apk"]

error

The base.apk file actually exists in the directory in question.

I have tried EVERYTHING (deep sigh)... cleaning from Android Studio, deleting the build folder time and time again, deleted the /data/app/ folder on my phone. All in vain :'-( I simply cannot figure out what to do. I even had a copy of my project folder named " - WORKING COPY". But now that doesn't even work. I'm beginning to think it's either my phone or Android Studio messing with me.

If someone can help me get my app up and running again it would be very much appreciated.

When that's done then I'm looking for a SIMPLE tutorial on how to implement runtime permission checks. Every single one I've found simply will not work. Before I broke my app I was able to debug it but all I could get was PERMISSION_DENIED.

I'm really at wits end here guys. Please help. Please...

Let me know what information I need to provide to get moving again. Or maybe take this to a different forum?

Comment: you may have hit dex limit after update, have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Unfortunately this did not make any difference :-(

Comment: what did you use to enable multidex?

Comment: I have minSdkVersion 20 so I added the lines to my build.gradle and added android:name to my manifest.

Comment: Just rebooted my phone and it seems to have fixed it. What a waste of the last 2-3 hrs :-( Thanks @OlegBogdanov for helping :-)